# How to put click-to-call directly into browser url

Tags: browser-addons

The

```
<a href="tel:1234567890">1234567890</a>
```

is used within an html page to signal `click to call`

But how to place a url directly on the browser address line?  I am most interested in `chrome` .

However

```
tel:1234567890
```

does not work: it simply brings up a google search results page.

Answer (score 0):

It would simply be tel:123456789

Comment: Updated OP.  That was the obvious thing to have (already) tried ..  I forgot to include that detail.

Comment: If that does not work, the browser does not know how to recognise the url, so you would need a plugin or different browser.

Comment: Well.. click to call works within an html - as shown in OP.  And I had also tried safari - with same (negative) result.